# How do I make a border around my whole screen for all the devices in Swift Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I have this game thats in landscape and I need a border around the whole screen so my heroNode can't go out of the screen on either of the four sides. I have this code but it only works for the iphone 5s and its too small for the other devices. How would I get the code to resize and fit the screen for the other devices? Thanks!

```
        override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRect(x: 20, y: -90, width: self.size.width-50, height: self.size.height))
    borderBody.categoryBitMask = borderbodycategory
    borderBody.collisionBitMask = HeroCategory
    borderBody.contactTestBitMask = HeroCategory
    borderBody.allowsRotation = false
    borderBody.affectedByGravity = false
    self.physicsBody = borderBody

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UIScreen` 's property instead of the fixed value.

```
let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width - 50
let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - 50
let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRect(x: 20, y: -90, width: width, height: height))
```

Comment: That code gives me a small rectangle on the bottom of my screen. I need it to be a border around the screen.

Comment: yea i did its still giving me a small rectangle

Comment: print out the width and height to dig more info.

Answer (score 6):

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
```

This gives your "World" a physicsbody, which is an edge, a loop, the size of the "World"'s frame.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a fixed value for your width, make use of percentage values so it scales with your screen size.

Comment: `width: self.size.width-50`, edit the -50 value to a percentage value that is most suitable for your playspace.